# weight update between shared variables in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have shared weights between two layers by the use of reuse property but I found that this actually shares the initial values of the variable. Optimizer updates the weights but that update is not reflected in the other layer.

```
with tf.variable_scope('conv1'): 
layer1 = conv2d(x,output_features=out_features,kernel_size=kernel_size,padding=padding,strides=strides)

with tf.variable_scope('conv1', reuse=True):
        layer1 = conv2d(x_shaped,output_features=out_features,kernel_size=kernel_size,padding=padding,strides=strides)
```

how can I reflect the updates on both of the layers?

Answer (score 1):

Give `conv2d` a name. By default the code will figure out a name so that it doesn't overlap, which causes 2 different variables to be created.

There should be a single set of variables. If you see two, then it's they are not shared.

Other than that, you are using variable_scope correctly. There's also `tf.AUTO_REUSE` if you want to wrap it in a function that you can reuse.

Comment: I can see only one variable and by using the same scope ensures that these are same variables. I printed the variables by tf.trainable_variables() and I got <tf.Variable 'under/conv1/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 1, 32) dtype=float32_ref>